# Hover event taking place outside of area I am wanting

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a small bug that I can't seem to locate. In my snippet you can see how whenever you hover over the image, opactiy and an image scale takes place, as well as a box comes over the image. That is perfect, but my issue is whenever you hover over the text below it, the hover effect takes place over the image.

I can't seem to figure out how for the hover effect to only take place when the mouse is hovering over the image.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```js
$('.home-img-block img').addClass(function() {
  return (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
});
```

```css
#home-img-block-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}
#home-img-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}
.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;

  position: relative;
}
.home-img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.home-img-block:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.home-img-container:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.home-img-container:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.home-img-block img {
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.home-img-block:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 33.33%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
#home-img-block-wording-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.home-img-wording-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.home-img-wording-block-title {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
.home-img-wording-block-description {
  padding: 25px 50px 0 50px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-block-section">
   <div id="home-img-blocks">
  <div class="home-img-block fadeBlock1">
    <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
   <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
   <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">WEB DESIGN</div>
   <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">The OD team can see your web design visions brought
   to life, creating a site that promotes your uniqueness through specific functionalities and features.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-img-block fadeBlock2">
    <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
   <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2new.jpg">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
   <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">ECOMMERCE</div>
   <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">Custom built solutions catered towards you end goal. 
   gfdgfdsg greg reg regrfesg fdsg gretswtgy tgreswt treswt trgegfd gsvbd fbgre greasgv drfdg greaag gredr</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="home-img-block fadeBlock3">
    <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class='home-img-container'>
   <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3new.jpg">
   <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-img-wording-blocks">
   <div class="home-img-wording-block-title">MARKETING STRATEGIES</div>
   <div class="home-img-wording-block-description">MARKETING STRATEGIES gfdgf fdggs gfsg gfsg gf sgf g  
   gfdsg sdfggfs gfdsgssdfg fdggfds gfdsg gfds gfdgs gf dsgfdsgfgs gfdgfs gtrg resg reg rgesgresrgrg</div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.home-img-block:hover .overlay
```

and

```
.home-img-block:hover img
```

replace them with

```
.home-img-container:hover .overlay

.home-img-container:hover img
```

otherwise you're triggering when you hover over the whole container instead of only wheen hovering the img one.